# ¿Por qué el femenino de "príncipe" es "princesa" y no "príncipa" o "principesa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, sinónimos

Muchos aprendimos la palabra italiano *principessa* viendo la película [La vida es bella](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film594480.html) (1997), cuando el personaje de Roberto Benigni saluda a su amada con un *buongiorno principessa*. Esto es, *buenos días princesa*.

Tiempo después, me parece curioso que el italiano y el español tengan palabras tan similares para príncipe (*principe*, sin tilde), mientras que princesa en castellano difiere mucho de esta raíz, que en italiano es *principessa* como vimos más arriba.

Mirando en el DRAE vemos:

> [**príncipe, princesa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UBt4jVS)
>
> Del latín *princeps*, *-ĭpis*; la forma femenina, del francés *princesse*, derivado de *prince* 'príncipe', y este del latín *princeps*.

Vaya, que *príncipe* vino directamente del latín, mientras que *princesa* pasó primero por el francés después de que en ese idioma adapataran el vocablo masculino.

Veo que ya en 1803 el diccionario actual recoge:

> Principesa. s.f. ant. Lo mismo que PRINCESA.

Y esto llega hasta hoy, donde el DRAE muestra:

> **principesa**
>   *De príncipe.*
>   1. f. p. us. princesa.

Donde *f. p. us.* quiere decir *nombre femenino poco usado*. Nótese además que aparece así desde 1817, mientras que la edición de 1780 no tiene dicha entrada.

¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Hubo un intento posterior de introducir *principesa*? ¿Por qué en primer lugar hubo ese paso por el francés? Y antes de usar el nombre proviniente del francés, ¿cuál se usaba?

Comment: Al parecer no existía la forma femenina. El príncipe era el hijo varón mayor del rey. El resto de hijos eran infantes o infantas (se puede encontrar el término "Infanta" en el CORDE en textos desde el siglo XI), como atestigua Covarrubias. La primera aparición de "Princesa" es casi llegando al siglo XV.

Comment: En ese caso, lo más probable es que la palabra *princesa* se usara para referirse a personas de otros países. Dado el uso del francés como lengua de prestigio durante la edad moderna, no es de extrañar que se usara ampliamente el título en esa lengua y de ahí pasó al castellano.

Comment: En la lengua española muchas palabras son irregulares, ya sea en verbos o en nombres. Por ejemplo: Actor y Actriz (Actora es incorrecto, aunque algunas personas lo dicen por desconocimiento o ignorancia).

Comment: Lo que es anormal en cuanto a la forma de *princesa*, la cosa que para mí indica que sí vino del francés, es que la raíz *princ-* no era castellana sino francesa. En otras parejas semejantes, la raíz original es obvia: *barón > baronesa,
conde > condesa,
marqués > marquesa,
duque > duquesa,
diácono > diaconisa,
alcalde > alcaldesa.* Hubiera sido más creíble pasar de *príncipe* a *principesa* y no a *princesa* si fuese completamente castellano en origen como vemos en el italiano dos siglos después. Véase también http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg.

Comment: @tchrist indudablemente, tu argumento tiene mucho sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que la forma "princesa" es más antigua de lo que yo pensaba en un principio:

> *Otrosi mandamos e ordenamos quelas otras gentes que vinieren ala dicha çibdad, asi dela nuestra corte commo de casa dela Reyna nuestra muger e del Principe e la Prinçesa e del infante Don Fernando nuestros fijos, commo quales quier otros que vinieren a nos e ala nuestra chançelleria, o alos nuestros contadores que fueren aposentados enla dicha çibdat o arrauales, quelos moradores o sennores delas posadas donde fueren aposentados les den aguisada mente, segund su poder, rropa en que duerma, e mesa e manteles e ollas e tajaderos e escudillas, segund que cada vno pudiere.*
>
> Anónimo, ["Cortes de Segovia"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100317%5C017%5CC000O10032017175415017.1212.1208&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20?r?ncipe%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1000-1400%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), 1390 (España).

Nótese la forma antigua "prinçesa". Y por el texto no parece que se refieran a príncipes y princesas de otros países (a lo mejor y como mucho del reino de al lado).

El texto más antiguo que he encontrado con la palabra es este:

> *Dixo el alcalde et el león pardo: -¿Cómmo fue eso?*
>   *El médico ignorante que envenenó a la princesa.*
>
> Anónimo, ["Calila e Dimna"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=2&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100317%5C018%5CC000O10032017180512250.1212.1208&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20?rin?esa%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1000-1400%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto2), 1251 (España).

*Calila e Dimna* es una colección de cuentos castellanos de 1251 probablemente mandada traducir por Alfonso X el Sabio siendo todavía infante. En este caso sí se usa la palabra "princesa" para hablar de princesas de reinos lejanos, ya que están basados en la literatura oriental, pero la palabra "princesa" ya está ahí.

El siguiente es este:

> Mas agora dexa aqui la ystoria a fablar de la çerca de escalona 
>   por contar como caso donna Costança la prinçesa de antiocha con Rinalt de 
>   castellon.
>
> Anónimo, ["Gran Conquista de Ultramar. Ms. 1187 BNM"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100317%5C018%5CC000O10032017180512250.1212.1208&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20?rin?esa%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1000-1400%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1), 1293 (España).

De nuevo usando la forma "prinçesa". Si nos vamos a "principesa", el primer uso que se encuentra en el CORDE es anterior a lo que piensas:

> *¡O prinçipessa e disponedora de gerarchías e todos estados, de pazes e guerras, e suertes e fados, sobre señores muy grande señora, 
>   así que tú eres la governadora e la medianera de aqueste grand mundo!*
>
> Juan de Mena, ["Laberinto de fortuna o las trescientas"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100317%5C018%5CC000O10032017181414671.1220.1216&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20?rin?ipe??a%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1400-1600%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), 1444 (España).

Sí que es cierto es que esta forma ha sido muy poco usada, encontrando el CORDE tan solo 5 casos entre variantes de "principesa" o "prinçipessa" o similares antes de 1700, por más de 7000 de variantes de "princesa". Esto es lo que hace que la forma "princesa" se recoja en los diccionarios desde el de Nebrija de 1495, mas no así la forma "principesa" que se incluyó mucho más recientemente.

Ahora bien, el diccionario de la RAE dice que la voz "princesa" vino dada por el francés. Veamos qué dice el *[Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/princesse)*:

> PRINCESSE, subst. fém. et adj. inv.
>   Étymol. et Hist. I. 1. Ca 1175 «dignité chez les Amazones» (Benoît, Ducs de Normandie, éd. C. Fahlin, 431); 2. 1320 «fille ou femme de prince» (Le Dit des Patenostres ds Nouv. Rec. de Fabliaux, éd. A. Jubinal, I, 239);

Es decir, en el siglo XII ya se usaba "princesse", por lo que es muy probable que la forma nos llegara desde el francés durante ese siglo o el siguiente, y adaptáramos la palabra a su versión más cercana en idioma español ("prinçesa" por aquel entonces). Si nos vamos al italiano, en [sapere.it](http://www.sapere.it/enciclopedia/princip%C3%A9ssa.html) vemos que la palabra "principéssa" se originó en ese idioma durante el siglo XIV, por lo que esa forma nos llegó más tarde (cuadra con el primer caso en el CORDE del siglo XV). Por tanto acabó siendo menos usada al haberse asentado ya la palabra "princesa".

Sobre lo que se decía antes de la llegada de la voz "princesa", parece que simplemente se decía "hija del rey":

> *Mas Josabet, la fija del rey, priso a Joas, que era fijo de los de Joram, e furtolo que non lo matasse [...].*
>
> Almerich, ["La fazienda de Ultra Mar"](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=9&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=100317%5C019%5CC000O10032017190010492.1220.1216&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20rey%20dist/3%20fij*%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1000-1200%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto9), c 1200 (España).

La falta de un término similar fue seguramente lo que propició la llegada de la voz del francés.

Comment: Añado una fuente online de la forma latina (no tengo a manos mis vocabularios latinos en papel, que son mucho mas completos) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/principissa . La fuente que menciona es el "Glossarium mediae et infimae Latinitatis" de finales del '800

Comment: @Bruno9779 interesante, pero dice que es del [nuevo latín](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Latin), no del latín antiguo, ¿no es así?

Comment: Si, latino "tardo" se le llama en Italiano. Cuando se habla de la lengua latina siempre hay que considerar que se habló por casi 2000 años y que cambió mucho en este tiempo. Además las lenguas "romanze" derivan casi enteramente del latino tardo. El típico ejemplo que hacen los profesores es lo de Cesar:  en la antiguedad tenía una pronuncia mas cercana a "Kaiser" que a la forma italiana "Chesare"

Comment: @Bruno9779 entiendo entonces que los términos "principéssa" del italiano y "principissa" del neolatín pudieron originarse en la misma época (siglo XIV), solo que por entonces a España ya había llegado "princesa" del francés.

Comment: Espléndida investigación, Carlos. Es un placer tener a una persona con tal capacidad de investigación y ganas de compartirla :)

Comment: @fedorqui el placer es mío. :) Esta pregunta se me había pasado y hoy por fin he encontrado tiempo para ponerme.